# Using the GPS (LocationManager) how To get the current Time?

Tags: java, android

I am developing one GPS Application. Which will send the location data to server for every one hour.

In this I am using following code:

```
location.getLatitude();
location.getLongitude();
location.getTime();
```

with this code I am getting Latitude and Longitude correctly and Time also, but I am getting some 13 digits number instead of the time. I done some research on that, I found that is an seconds for of the current time.

so now I need to convert that 13 digit number in to the specific format.

Comment: can you please share (location object's) Class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Location#getTime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime%28%29) returns *"the UTC time of this fix, in milliseconds since January 1, 1970."*

This is exactly the same behavior as [`java.util.Date#getTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29). I'm not clear on what you'd like to do with this time data, but if you'd like to convert the `Location`'s time into a `java.util.Date`, you can do it like this:

```
long time = location.getTime();
Date date = new Date(time);
```

Now it is somewhat easier to work with. If you'd like to create a particular string output format of that date, use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String text = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(text); // prints something like 2011-01-08 13:35:48
```

---

That said, if all you'd like to do is get the current time (which is what it sounds like you're trying to do) you don't need a `Location` at all:

```
Date now = new Date();
```

That's it!

---

Does that help? If not, could you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to send the Time with Location at what time that Location is captured that time, I have to send to server not the current time

Comment: Thanks Matt for your valuable reply.. it helps me alot

Comment: Hello Matt, You have any idea to get the NMEA sentence of the location I used NmeaListener but no result.. help me get that NMEA sentence and display that in my device by using the TextView t = (TextView)findById(R.id.TextView1); t.append("Location in NMEA Format:"+nmea); how is it possible.. give me your suggestion and if possible code lines which are gives that output

Comment: @Jagan: please ask a new question for this issue. I have no idea what NMEA is.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Date date = new Date(location.getTime());

 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

 String myDate= sdf.format(date);



 System.out.println(myDate)
```

Comment: this code help you to getting date and time using GPS in java and android.

Answer (score 1):

```
String timestamp = parseDate(location.getTime().toDate());

public String parseDate(Date date){
        String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
        return sdf.format(date).toString();
}
```