# android gps getTime(), which time?

Tags: android

does it give the cellphone's time or the cell phone network's time or gps satellite time? I would like to convert the time to EST is that possible? assuming users are from around world?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634053/using-the-gps-locationmanager-how-to-get-the-current-time

Comment: so the gps satellite gives the time based on user's time zone setting?

Comment: Yes, check this it may help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22429091/3036759

Answer (score -1):

Since `getTime()`

> Return the UTC time of this fix, in milliseconds since January 1,
>   1970.

you can use the method described **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313087/how-to-convert-date-and-time-to-est-format-in-android)** to convert from Date in milliseconds to EST Format.