# Get the current Date And Time Using LocationManager

Tags: android

I tried this metthod : Is there any  other method? Date and time must follow GMT+6.00.

```
LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        assert locMan != null;
        long networkTS = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getTime();
```

Comment: check it -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634053/using-the-gps-locationmanager-how-to-get-the-current-time

Answer (score 0):

This will help you meet your requirement.

Try Below Code :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+6:00"));  
Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
```